# why this jquery functions not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written very simple code, here is the html code:

```
<form name="signInForm">
    <section id="signInSection">
        <input class="large" type="text" placeholder="username" />
        <br>
        <input class="large" type="password" placeholder="password">
        <br>
        <button id="signinbtn" class="small">Sign In</button>
        <br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" />Remember me.</label>
        <a href="#">Reset Password</a>

        <img src="../images/cancel.jpg" alt="Cancel Sign In">
    </section>
</form>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$('#signinbtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#signInSection').fadeOut(200);       
    $('#signedInSection').fadeIn(200);
    $('.signUp').fadeOut(1);
    $('.signIn').closest('header').find('input').fadeIn(200);
    $('#memberToolBarSection').fadeIn(1500);
    $('#contents').fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Whatever I write inside the above mentioned click handler, it is not working. Although I tested by putting an alert that the handler is getting invoked.

Can anyone please tell me why it is not invoking all the fadeIn and fadeOut function calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this...

```
$('#signinbtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#signInSection').fadeOut(200);       
    $('#signedInSection').fadeIn(200);
    $('.signUp').fadeOut(1);
    $('.signIn').closest('header').find('input').fadeIn(200);
    $('#memberToolBarSection').fadeIn(1500);
    $('#contents').fadeIn(1500);
});
```

It looks like the form is being submitted, which in this case just reloads the page.

Adding the `e` parameter to the event handler and adding `e.preventDefault()` will stop the form submitting.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wPByT/)

Comment: It is working with event.preventDefault(). But I have not given method="post" in the form then why it is submitting?

Comment: If you haven't specified a method or action then the default behaviour of a form is to submit a GET to the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not because the form is being submitted so you're being redirected?  If that is the case, change your handler to the following:

```
$('#signinbtn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#signInSection').fadeOut(200);       
    $('#signedInSection').fadeIn(200);
    $('.signUp').fadeOut(1);
    $('.signIn').closest('header').find('input').fadeIn(200);
    $('#memberToolBarSection').fadeIn(1500);
    $('#contents').fadeIn(1500);
});
```

The crucial line being
    e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/4VE76/1/)**

Try this

`e.preventDefault();` prevent it from submitting the form after animations `$("#signInForm").submit();` will submit the form where `signInForm` is the form `id`

### html

```
<form name="signInForm" id="signInForm">
                <section id="signInSection">
                    <input class="large" type="text" placeholder="username"/><br>
                    <input class="large" type="password" placeholder="password"><br>    
                    <button id="signinbtn" class="small">Sign In</button><br>
                    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Remember me.</label>
                    <a href="#">Reset Password</a>
                    <img src="../images/cancel.jpg" alt="Cancel Sign In">   
                </section>
            </form>
```

### code

```
$('#signinbtn').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    $('#signInSection').fadeOut(200);       
    $('#signedInSection').fadeIn(200);
    $('.signUp').fadeOut(1);
    $('.signIn').closest('header').find('input').fadeIn(200);
    $('#memberToolBarSection').fadeIn(1500);
    $('#contents').fadeIn(1500);
    $("#signInForm").submit();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try This one

```
 $('form').on('click', '#signinbtn', function () {
    $('#signInSection').fadeOut(200);       
    $('#signedInSection').fadeIn(200);
    $('.signUp').fadeOut(1);
    $('.signIn').closest('header').find('input').fadeIn(200);
    $('#memberToolBarSection').fadeIn(1500);
    $('#contents').fadeIn(1500);
});
```